# Group and sort JSON in Javascript while maintaining the original keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I'm looking for a way to transform this kind of JSON:

```js
{  
   "component-0":{  
  "parent":"grid-item-0",
  "position":1
   },
   "component-1":{  
  "parent":"grid-item-0",
  "position":0
   },
   "component-2":{  
  "parent":"grid-item-1",
  "position":0
   } ...
}
```

into this (grouped by "parent" and sorted by "position"):

```js
{  
   "grid-item-0":[  
      {  
         "id":"component-1",
         "parent":"grid-item-1",
         "position":0
      },
      {  
         "id":"component-0",
         "parent":"grid-item-0",
         "position":1
      }
   ],
   "grid-item-1":[  
      {  
         "id":"component-2",
         "parent":"grid-item-1",
         "position":0
      }
   ] ...
}
```

Note that it's important to keep the original key/identifier ("component-0" etc.) after grouping. I tried the underscore groupBy method, however it replaces my id with a number.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var obj = {  
   "component-0":{  
  "parent":"grid-item-0",
  "position":1
   },
   "component-1":{  
  "parent":"grid-item-0",
  "position":0
   },
   "component-2":{  
  "parent":"grid-item-1",
  "position":0
   }
}

_.each(obj, (v, k) => v.id = k)
var grouped = _.groupBy(obj, 'parent');
var sorted = _.mapObject(grouped, v => _.sortBy(v,'position'))
console.log(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using lodash, as it is not providing mapObject, should I use _.map or is there any better method for this?

Comment: @hardiksa I think in lodash its called mapValues

Answer (score 1):

**A vanilla JS solution:**

First we need to convert the original object into an array of objects, adding the `id` to each:

```
var objects = Object.keys(original_object).
  reduce(function(arr, key) {
    arr.push(
      Object.assign({}, original_object[key], { id: key })
    );
    return arr;
  }, []);
```

This will give us an array with the following structure:

[image]

Then we sort `objects` by position:

```
var sorted_objects = objects.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.position >= b.position ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Finally, we group the objects by `parent`:

```
var groups = sorted_objects.reduce(function(res, item) {
  res[item.parent] = res[item.parent] || [];
  res[item.parent].push(item);
  return res;
}, {});
```

The end result:

[image]

---

**The final code:**

```js
var original_object = {  
  "component-0":{  
    "parent":"grid-item-0",
    "position":1
  },
  "component-1":{  
    "parent":"grid-item-0",
    "position":0
  },
  "component-2":{  
    "parent":"grid-item-1",
    "position":0
  }
}

var objects = Object.keys(original_object).
  reduce(function(arr, key) {
    arr.push(
      Object.assign({}, original_object[key], { id: key })
    );
    return arr;
  }, []);

var sorted_objects = objects.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.position >= b.position ? 1 : -1;
});

var groups = sorted_objects.reduce(function(res, item) {
  res[item.parent] = res[item.parent] || [];
  res[item.parent].push(item);
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast and detailed reply. Looks exactly like what I was hoping for, will try this as soon as I can.

Comment: If you have underscore.js included anyway, then go with @juvian's solution instead, as it's a lot more concise.